# Access Top N Query where N is given in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in MS SQL Server. Table2 has the following:

```
TaskId TopN
1       2
2       3
3       1
```

Table1 has the following:

```
TaskId TopN Value
1       2     12
1       2     12
1       2     12
2       3      1
2       3      1
2       3      5
2       3     12
2       3      8
2       3      5
```

I want to be able to select the top N records based on the TopN field in table2 (which is the same TopN value found in table1, so maybe I don't even need to bother using two tables). The desired output should be as follows:

```
TaskId  TopN  Value
1         2      12
1         2      12
2         3      12
2         3       8
2         3       5
```

I have tried the below SQL statement, but it skips TaskId=1. Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

```
SELECT  DISTINCT    T1.TaskId, 
        T1.TopN, 
        T1.values 
FROM        Table1 T1 INNER JOIN Table1 T2 ON
            T1.TaskId = T2.TaskId AND
            T1.TopN = T2.TopN AND
            T1.Value <= T2.Value
GROUP BY    T1.TaskId, 
        T1.TopN, 
        T1.Value 
        
HAVING      COUNT(*) <= (
                     SELECT TopN
                     FROM   table2
                     WHERE  table2.TaskID = T1.TaskId
                    )
```

Comment: Are you using MS Access or SQL Server?  Please tag correctly.

Comment: SQL server. sorry about that. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that in the question you have named Table2 as the one which has the fields - TaskId, TopN, Values however in your query you have used the opposite. Assuming Table2 is the one which has the details, you can use the query below to get the desired result. You would not need to use the other table (Table1 - as per the question) which has just the task_id and topN since all the info is already present in Table2.

```
Select Taskid, TopN, Values
from
(Select T1.*, row_number() over(partition by Taskid order by Values desc) As rnk 
from Table2 T1) Tb
where Tb.TopN >= Tb.rnk;
```

** Fixed the typo in the code (changed to >= instead of <=), it should work fine now.

Comment: Thanks Somy. I have edited my question to point to the correct table (it should be Table1 now having all the data). I have tried your SQL statement in MS SQL Server, but for TaskId=2 values I expect the Top 3 values only. I'm getting four rows for TaskId=2 and they're not the Top 3.

Comment: also note (if it affects in any way): all data types are 'int'. I can changed them to any data type if it can get me the output I need, which is selecting the Top N values where 'N' is equal to the value shown in TopN column.

Comment: Oops, I made a typo. It should be topN >= rank and not the other way around. I have fixed it in my answer so it should work fine now. Thanks!   Here is the demo link - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3685d673ee67feb2d07625c82fb8d11a

Comment: Somy, it worked like a charm! I have accepted your answer. The link you provided with the sample was very useful. Amazing the things you can do with those SQL functions.

Comment: Great to know!! Thanks for your feedback, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have *three* rows with the same values -- and 3 > 2.  That is, the subquery returns "3" which is not less than "2".  In SQL Server, you would do this much more simply using `row_number()`.

If you are using MS Access, you need a column that distinguishes the rows.

EDIT:

In SQL Server, you would use:

```
select t1.*
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by taskid order by value desc) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
where t1.seqnum <= t1.topn;
```

Comment: It's in SQL Server (I updated my question - thanks). How do I go about using row_number() in this scenario?